# SQL Server 2008 - CAST to nvarchar not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the following SQL statement as part of a trigger that is not working and cant figure out why:

```
DECLARE @Orderid INT
DECLARE @CountOfOrderItems INT
DECLARE @EmployeeID INT
DECLARE @EmployeeName NVARCHAR

SELECT @Orderid = DELETED.id

SET @CountOfOrderItems = (select count(*) from OrderDetails where OrderID = @Orderid)

SET @EmployeeName = (SELECT Firstname + ' ' + Lastname from Employees where employees.id = 
                      (SELECT employeeid from Orders where Orders.id = @Orderid))

        INSERT INTO applicationlog (Sourceobject,Logtype,Message)
        VALUES ('Orders table',
                'Order deleted',
                'Order with ' + CAST(@CountOfOrderItems as varchar) + ' items deleted by '+ CAST(@EmployeeName as nvarchar))
```

The column datatypes for the applicationlog table are all `nvarchar(255)` for sourceobject and logtype and `nvarchar(max)` for message.

The issue is, when I include the `CAST(@EmployeeName as nvarchar)` bit, nothing is entered in the message column, and it shows null. Data is entered in the other two columns. Casting the employeename as `varchar` also doesn't work.

When I remove the bit shown in bold above and use the following code, it works and the casting for the countoforderitems works.

```
INSERT INTO applicationlog (Sourceobject,Logtype,Message)
VALUES ('Orders table',
        'Order deleted',
        'Order with ' + CAST(@CountOfOrderItems as varchar) + ' items deleted')
```

I have no idea why and would appreciate some help, as I need to log the user that is deleting the record.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks to all that have responded. I declared employeename as a **VARCHAR(255)** and edited the insert statement to

```
        INSERT INTO applicationlog (Sourceobject,Logtype,Message)
    values ('Orders table','Order deleted','Order with ' + CAST(@CountOfOrderItems as varchar(255)) + ' items deleted by ' + coalesce(@EmployeeName,''))
```

and now all information is there except the @Employeename which i think is returning an empty string, even though the employee exists in the table.So in the last column i now have **"3 items deleted by "**

Which is better than the null before, but why is the @Employeename blank?

Comment: @EmployeeName is already NVARCHAR in declaration, why are you casting it? And If it's null, your whole concat will be NULL, you have to do some checking and add empty string if it's NULL - COALESCE(@EmployeeName, '')... Also like mentioned you should set a length every time, when you declare it without length, default is 1

Comment: Your trigger appears to be broken - `deleted` is a table that may contain 0, 1, or *multiple* rows. Assigning values from it to a scalar variable, `SELECT @Orderid = DELETED.id` is flawed (if that even works - I'd have thought you still need a `FROM` clause for that query).

Comment: Damien - my understanding is that the trigger runs when a record ie one row is deleted? Please correct me if im wrong. and yes the SELECT @orderid does return a value and the syntax did look odd  but there are other triggers here that use it and work fine.cheers

Answer (score 2):

You are using `nvarchar` (or `varchar` or `nchar` or `char`) without a length in at least three places.  *Do not do this.*  The default length varies by context.  So:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeName NVARCHAR
```

Is really:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeName NVARCHAR(1)
```

And

```
CAST(@CountOfOrderItems as varchar)
```

is really:

```
CAST(@CountOfOrderItems as varchar(30))
```

(Okay, this is probably ok).

So, be explicit about the lengths.  You do not need to cast `@EmployeeName` for the string concatenation.  And, you do not need to use `set` because you can set the value of a variable in a `select` statement:

```
DECLARE @Orderid INT;
DECLARE @CountOfOrderItems INT;
DECLARE @EmployeeID INT;
DECLARE @EmployeeName NVARCHAR(255);

SELECT @Orderid = DELETED.id;  -- This looks strange.  I think you are missing a `from` clause

select  @CountOfOrderItems = count(*)
from OrderDetails
where OrderID = @Orderid);

SELECT @EmployeeName = Firstname + ' ' + Lastname
from Employees
where employees.id = (SELECT employeeid from Orders where Orders.id = @Orderid));

INSERT INTO applicationlog (Sourceobject, Logtype, Message)
    VALUES ('Orders table',
            'Order deleted',
            'Order with ' + CAST(@CountOfOrderItems as varchar(8000)) + ' items deleted by '+ @EmployeeName ;
```

Or, I would just dispense with all the intermediate stuff and do:

```
INSERT INTO applicationlog (Sourceobject, Logtype, Message)
    SELECT 'Orders table', 'Order deleted',
           replace(replace('Order with @n items deleted by @by',
                           '@n', count(od.orderid)
                          ), '@by', e.Firstname + ' ' + e.Lastname
                  )
    FROM deleted d JOIN
         orders o
         on d.id = o.orderId JOIN
         employees e
         on o.employeeid = e.employeeid LEFT JOIN
         orderdetails od
         on od.orderid = o.orderid;
```

I think a single query better shows the intention of what you are doing and you don't need to issue a bunch of queries and assign variables.

Comment: thanks for your response Gordon. i tried out your single query solution but got an error. i edited some table names on it but still got 2 errors, both relating to the firstname and lastname -The error is "Column 'employees.Lastname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: i edited this bit                           FROM deleted d JOIN
         orders o
         on d.id = o.Id JOIN
         employees e
         on o.employeeid = e.id LEFT JOIN
         orderdetails od
         on od.orderid = o.id

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing datatypes here. If you want it to be nvarchar then it all needs to be Nvarchar. You should also specify the lengths you want like so:

```
VALUES ('Orders table',
                'Order deleted',
                N'Order with ' + CAST(@CountOfOrderItems as Nvarchar(10)) + N' items deleted by '+ CAST(@EmployeeName as nvarchar(10)))
```

This all being said I don't know why you are casting @EmployeeName as an Nvarchar when you've already declared it as Nvarchar, it seems a redundant process.

If your @EmployeeName is null it will also show null for the whole string, to get around this you can use the following statement at the top of you query:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
```